oct 30/31 updates
Been running GPU intensive workloads including some gaming. Namely Steam apps that have been working for months. Kernel update today suddenly causing wayland/x + nvidia issues in that it feels that the nvidia driver is crashing causing X/w/e to wedge along with it. Have  console and ssh access but gdm and all ui is unfunctional. would appreciate some insight on this matter, as all signs point to recent updates.

Your details are vague & give us nothing we can currently help with. You don't mention what Ubuntu product, as deb packages are built for specific releases, so unless you're talking about a snap package update we have no specifics. Also do you update daily? as unless you do a date means nothing, also what mirror are you using? as mirrors can get behind, so again specifics are required. As you have access to your setup, your mirror, release & what updates you actually received - why not give specifics. Your release may also be a LTS thus kernel stack matters, but you've not told us.
